# How to delete item from listbox at particular location in C#

Tags: c#, listbox

How can I delete an item from listbox at particular location and not the SELECTED one?

Let's say if I have 4 items in listbox and I want to delete the one at index 2, how can I do that without selecting it.

Comment: which platform? ASP.NET Silverlight Winform?

Comment: In that case: WPF or Windows Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ListBox.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) should be a List. More precise a [ListBox.ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.aspx)

Have you tried :

```
myListBox.Items.RemoveAt(2);
```

[RemoveAt refference in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(anyindex);
```